# Serialize internal Javascript objects (like Range)

Tags: javascript, range, serialization

I'd like to store some internal Javascript object like Range but I haven't found a way to save it. What's the best way to save it ? 
I thought to serialize it but I haven't found anything on the net.

Is there a library that helps doing that? jquery?

Answer (score 2):

If it's specifically Ranges, then save the range as a relative object, then turn it into a simple string equivalent,

e.g.

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if ( sel && sel.rangeCount > 0 ) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var sC = range.startContainer, eC = range.endContainer;
    
    
    var A = [];
    while (sC !== editor && sC) {
        A.push(getNodeIndex(sC));
        sC = sC.parentNode;
    }
    
    
    var B = [];
    while (eC && eC !== editor) {
        B.push(getNodeIndex(eC));
        eC = eC.parentNode;
    }
    if ( B.length==0 ) {
        B=A;
        eC=sC;
    }

    var caretPosition = {"sC": A, "sO": range.startOffset, "eC": B, "eO": range.endOffset};
```

Then turn that into a string if required:

```
function getCP2String() {
   return _caretPosition.sC+';'+_caretPosition.sO+';'+_caretPosition.eC+';'+_caretPosition.eO;
}
```

Then reverse this if/when necessary:

```
function doRestoreFromString(serialTx) {   

   caretPosition.sC=serialTx.split(';')[0].split(',');
   _caretPosition.sO=serialTx.split(';')[1].split(',');
   _caretPosition.eC=serialTx.split(';')[2].split(',');
   _caretPosition.eO=serialTx.split(';')[3].split(',');

   console.log('sC='+_caretPosition.sC);
   console.log('sO='+_caretPosition.sO);
   console.log('eC='+_caretPosition.eC);
   console.log('eO='+_caretPosition.eO);

   doRestoreRange();
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/2gr1vchm/ for a full working example.

Comment: Extremely interesting